# Remove nested <SPAN> without ID

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Ok, I have the following string

I have a string that contains the following:

```
<span>A</span>BC<span id="blabla">D<span>EF</span></span>GH
```

I want to be able to use pure JavaScript to strip out any span tag that does not have an id so that the output looks like:

```
ABC<span id="blabla">DEF</span>GH
```

I have the following code which works fine but does not handle the nested span in the middle (the one that holds EF). I just need to know how can I use recursion to accomplish my goal.

```
function removeSpans2(s) {
  var a = document.createElement('div');
  a.innerHTML = s;
  var node, next = a.firstChild;

  while (node = next) {
    next = next.nextSibling

    if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && !node.id) {
      a.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(node.textContent || node.innerText), node);
    }
  }
  return a.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recursion needed, figured out a simpler algorithm. This one handles all sorts of nested elements, you can have A elements inside the spans, or spans in side As, or spans in spans in spans... whatever.

```
function removeSpans3(s) {
  var a = document.createElement('div');
  a.innerHTML = s;
  var span, spans = a.getElementsByTagName('span');
  var frag, arr = [];

  // Stabilise spans collection in array
  for (var i=0, iLen=spans.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    arr[i] = spans[i];
  }

  // Process spans
  for (i=0; i<iLen; i++) {
    span = arr[i];

    // If no id, put content into a fragment
    if (!span.id) {

      // Some older IEs may not like createDocumentFragment
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

      while (span.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(span.firstChild);
      }

      // Replace span with its content in the fragment
      span.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, span);
    }
  }
  return a.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. You really saved my day. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perfect time to pull out some recursion:

```
function removeSpans2(s) {
  var a = document.createElement('div');
  a.innerHTML = s;
  var node, next = a.firstChild;

  while (node = next) {
    next = next.nextSibling

    if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && !node.id) {
      a.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(removeSpans2(node.textContent || node.innerText)), node);
    } else if (node.innerText != undefined){
        var node2 = node.cloneNode(true);
        node2.innerText = removeSpans2(node2.innerText);
        a.replaceChild(node2, node);
    }
  }
  return a.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a.replaceChild(node2,node) in line 14?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, just add a recursion

```
function removeSpans2(s , el) {
    var a = el || document.createElement('div');
    a.innerHTML = s;

    var node, next = a.firstChild;

    while (node = next) {
        next = next.nextSibling;
        if( node.children && node.children.length ) {
            arguments.callee(node.innerHTML , node);
        }else if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && !node.id) {
            a.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(node.textContent || node.innerText), node);
        }
    }
    return a.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you simply just use String.replace() if it is an html string like you seemed to indicate.

```
str.replace(/<span>([A-Za-z0-9]*)<\/span>/g, '$1');
```

You can tweak the values between the brackets to accommodate for what content you would find between your spans

**EDIT** edited above code to remove just the tags and not the content inside

Comment: The OP only wants to remove the tags from the markup, not its content.

Comment: ok so simply do this str.replace(/<span>([A-Za-z0-9]*)<\/span>/g, '$1');

Comment: Easy, clean and yet cleaver. I love how simple and easy it is to get the job done.

Comment: @andbeyond - doesn't work for nested spans like `<span>asd<span id="foo">asdas</span>asdf</span>` or spans with other content. You can't parse non-trivial HTML with a regular expression.